# app for better calls

Tags: applications, calls

when I talk with someone over facebook messenger the voice quality is unbleivable, the other person can hear a mosquito flying

But when I call someone normal over the phone, the voice is very weak

So I know it is not from my phone because I have the problem on 2 different phones from different brands, so is there any app that can manage the calls with a voice quality like facebook messenger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are they both on the same carrier? If so, it could simply be a bad cellular connection or just a bad network. A different voice app shouldn't fix that, if it is happening on two different phones.

You could try communicating with people using a messaging app, such as calling on Messenger, or if you don't want to do that try a different messaging app that can call such as Viber, WhatsApp, or Signal (which uses E2E encryption, by the way). They are all available in the [communication section](https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/COMMUNICATION) of Google Play. I would link them, but I just joined the site and don't have enough reputation.

If you want to be able to call real numbers, without the recipient having to download an app, you should be able to try [Hangouts Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.hangoutsdialer). Hangouts Dialer calls real numbers using the Google Voice telephony system, so you can call your friends through a phone number provided by Google. It should provide decent sound quality, as long as you have a fair network connection.

If you have any more questions, please comment and let me know. I hope this helped!